# How to use YouTube Data API

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried using YouTube Data API.
I really took a good look at everything I found on the internet. The code itself isn't the problem, but I did not find out, where to use this code. Do I simply create a python file (in Visual Studio Code for example) and run it there? Because it didn't work when I tried this...
I also saw many people using the API with the commander only, others used something in chrome (localhost:8888...). So I don`t really know what's the way to go or what I should do.

Thanks for any help :)
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python developer but as a guess you could start here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

using pip to install the dependencies you need.

You should be able to create a simple python file that authenticates with the API and then calls a method on the on the google api client and then output it. There are some examples here:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have python installed on your PC
2. Create a project: [Google’s APIs and Services dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/apis/dashboard)
3. Enable the Youtube v3 API: [API Library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library)
4. Create credentials: [Credentials wizard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/wizard?)
5. Now you need to get an access token and a refresh token using the credentials you created
6. Find an authentication example in one of the following libraries:

   - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client
   - https://github.com/omarryhan/aiogoogle (for the async version)
7. Copy and paste the client ID and client secret you got from step 4 and paste them in the authentication example you found in step 6 (Should search for an OAuth2 example), this step should provide with an access token and a refresh token
8. Copy and paste a Youtube example from either:

   - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client
   - https://github.com/omarryhan/aiogoogle (for the async version)
9. Replace the access token and refresh token fields with the ones you got.

Now you should be able to run the file from any terminal by typing:

```sh
python3 yourfile.py
```

---

## [EDIT]

The API key is not the same as the access token. There are 2 main ways to authenticate with Google APIs:

1. Access and refresh token
2. API_KEY.

API key won't work with personal info. You need to get an access and refresh token for that (method 1).

Once you get an access token, it acts in a similar fashion to the API_KEY you got. Getting an access token is a bit more complicated than only working with an API_KEY.

A refresh token is a token you get with the access token upon authentication. Access tokens expire after 3600 seconds. When they expire, your authentication library asks Google's servers for a new access token with the refresh token. The refresh token has a very long lifetime (often indefinite), so make sure you store it securely.

To get an access token and a refresh token (user credentials), you must first create **client credentials**. Which should consists of 1. a client ID and 2. a client secret. These are just normal strings.

You should also, set a redirect URL in your Google app console in order to properly perform the OAuth2 flow. The OAuth2 flow is the authentication protocol that many APIs rely on to allow them to act on a user's account with the consent of the user. (e.g. when an app asks you to post on your behalf or control your account on your behalf, it typically will use this protocol.)

Aiogoogle's docs does a decent job in explaining the authentication flow(s) available by Google.

https://aiogoogle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But this is an async Python library. If you're not familiar with the async syntax, you can read the docs just to get a general idea of how the authentication system works and then apply it to Google's sync Python library.

About point no.6. The links I posted with Aiogoogle being one of them, are just client libraries that help you access Google's API quicker and with less boilerplate. Both libraries have documentation, where they have links to examples on how to use them. So, open the documentation, read it, search for the examples posted, try to understand how the code in the example(s) work. Then maybe download it and run it on your own machine.

I recommend that your read the [docs](https://aiogoogle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!
I do not understand exactly what step 5 and 6. are.
I created a project, enabled youtube v3 API, created credentials.

I have the API key (is it the same as access token), and what is the refresh token?
And could you explain point 6. a little further please?

Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: I edited the answer to answer your comment. Read from after the title: \[Edit]. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
  /// <summary>
  /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: upload a video.
  /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
  /// See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
  /// </summary>
  internal class UploadVideo
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
      Console.WriteLine("==============================");

      try
      {
        new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
      UserCredential credential;
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
      }


      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
      });

      var video = new Video();
      video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
      video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
      video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
      video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
      video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
      video.Status = new VideoStatus();
      video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
      var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
      {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
      }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
      switch (progress.Status)
      {
        case UploadStatus.Uploading:
          Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
          break;

        case UploadStatus.Failed:
          Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
          break;
      }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }
  }
}
```